# Error combine jasper report with java servlet

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am generating reports using jasperReports in dwr.i am getting these errors

```
INFO: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:4: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:5: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;
^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:13: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:15: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*;
^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol: class JREvaluator
public class classic_1314606689888_793831 extends JREvaluator
                                                  ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_LOCALE = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_JASPER_REPORT = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_VIRTUALIZER = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_TIME_ZONE = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_SORT_FIELDS = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_SCRIPTLET = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:35: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_CONNECTION = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_CLASS_LOADER = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_DATA_SOURCE = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_URL_HANDLER_FACTORY = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_MAX_COUNT = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:43: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_TEMPLATES = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillParameter parameter_REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillField field_sach_MaSach = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:46: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillField field_sach_TenSach = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:47: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillField field_sach_MaNhaXuatBan = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillField field_sach_GiaBan = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:49: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillField field_sach_SoLuongTon = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:50: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillField field_sach_MaTheLoai = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillVariable variable_PAGE_NUMBER = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillVariable variable_COLUMN_NUMBER = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillVariable variable_REPORT_COUNT = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_13146
INFO: 06689888_793831.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillVariable variable_PAGE_COUNT = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:55: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
    private JRFillVariable variable_COLUMN_COUNT = null;
            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:78: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_LOCALE = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_LOCALE");
                                   ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:79: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_JASPER_REPORT = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("JASPER_REPORT");
                                   ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:80: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_VIRTUALIZER = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_VIRTUALIZER");
                                        ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:81: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_TIME_ZONE = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_TIME_ZONE");
                                      ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:82: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_SORT_FIELDS = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("SORT_FIELDS");
                                 ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:83: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER");
                                          ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:84: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_SCRIPTLET = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_SCRIPTLET");
                                      ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:85: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP");
                                           ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:86: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_CONNECTION = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_CONNECTION");
                                       ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:87: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_CLASS_LOADER = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_CLASS_LOADER");
                                         ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:88: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_DATA_SOURCE = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_DATA_SOURCE");
                                        ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_URL_HANDLER_FACTORY = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_URL_HANDLER_FACTORY");
                                                ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:90: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION");
                                          ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:91: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY");
                                           ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:92: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_MAX_COUNT = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_MAX_COUNT");
                                      ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:93: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_TEMPLATES = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_TEMPLATES");
                                      ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:94: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillParameter
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        parameter_REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE = (JRFillParameter)pm.get("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE");
                                            ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:103: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        field_sach_MaSach = (JRFillField)fm.get("sach_MaSach");
                             ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:104: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        field_sach_TenSach = (JRFillField)fm.get("sach_TenSach");
                              ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:105: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        field_sach_MaNhaXuatBan = (JRFillField)fm.get("sach_MaNhaXuatBan");
                                   ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:106: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        field_sach_GiaBan = (JRFillField)fm.get("sach_GiaBan");
                             ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:107: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        field_sach_SoLuongTon = (JRFillField)fm.get("sach_SoLuongTon");
                                 ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:108: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillField
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        field_sach_MaTheLoai = (JRFillField)fm.get("sach_MaTheLoai");
                                ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:117: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        variable_PAGE_NUMBER = (JRFillVariable)vm.get("PAGE_NUMBER");
                                ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:118: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class
INFO:  classic_1314606689888_793831
        variable_COLUMN_NUMBER = (JRFillVariable)vm.get("COLUMN_NUMBER");
                                  ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:119: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        variable_REPORT_COUNT = (JRFillVariable)vm.get("REPORT_COUNT");
                                 ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:120: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        variable_PAGE_COUNT = (JRFillVariable)vm.get("PAGE_COUNT");
                               ^
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\classic_1314606689888_793831.java:121: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class JRFillVariable
location: class classic_1314606689888_793831
        variable_COLUMN_COUNT = (JRFillVariable)vm.get("COLUMN_COUNT");
                                 ^
61 errors
```

please help me this regard to generate report

Comment: Can you confirm that the jasperreports jars are packaged in your WAR? It appears as if the the report compiler cannot locate the right packages since they're not in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding jasperreports*.jar and any other jar containing classes referenced in the report under glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext.
Restart the app server.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the JasperReport library is missing. The latest version of JasperReports can be downloaded here http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.5.0/

Add the jar file to your project and redeploy.

Make sure you have the required dependencies as well: http://www.installationwiki.org/JasperReports

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add JDT libraries in the classpath of your application. (WEB-INF/lib)

`jdtcore and jdt-compiler`

At the time of this writing versions 3.1.0 and 3.1.1 respectively will work for jasperreports 4.7.0.

This error happens only in glassfish as far as I now. In tomcat this problem does not occur.

[Jasper FAQ: When should I compile my report templates and how?](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/faq.html?group_id=252#FAQ22)

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same errors, but when using with Groovy and Jasperreports.
I get these errors:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
/home/avorsterman/dev/prj/groovy/page1_1641570877927_139275.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public class page1_1641570877927_139275 extends JREvaluator
                                                ^
  symbol: class JREvaluator
/home/avorsterman/dev/prj/groovy/page1_1641570877927_139275.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    private JRFillVariable variable_PAGE_NUMBER = null;
            ^
  symbol:   class JRFillVariable
  location: class page1_1641570877927_139275
/home/avorsterman/dev/prj/groovy/page1_1641570877927_139275.java:4: error: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
^
/home/avorsterman/dev/prj/groovy/page1_1641570877927_139275.java:5: error: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;
^
/home/avorsterman/dev/prj/groovy/page1_1641570877927_139275.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
        variable_PAGE_NUMBER = (JRFillVariable)vm.get("PAGE_NUMBER");
                                ^
  symbol:   class JRFillVariable
  location: class page1_1641570877927_139275
5 errors
```

After adding this dependency to the project the errors are fixed:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```